# Sending variables to Symfony template file

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, twig

I'm trying to send a variable to a twig file which is not in the typical location, Usually I'm loading views by specifying their path through the Bundle but the file I want to send a variable to is not, hierarchically, on the same level as the other twig templates.

I've a controller which looks like the following:

```
public function fooAction(Request $request)
{

   *//Query*

    return $this->render('Bundle:file.html.twig', array('varToSend' => $queryResult));
}
```

I'm pretty sure the Bundle:file.html.twig is wrong but I don't know how else to specify the relevant path in twig.

Comment: What is the path to `file.html.twig`?  What is the path to `Bundle`?

Answer (score 3):

Twig you would get from container would not work with arbitrary paths, but you can initialize your own twig:

```
$twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
$rendered = $twig->render(
  file_get_contents('/path/to/your/file.html.twig'),
  array('varToSend' => $queryResult)
);
```

If you need this in more than one place, consider making it a Symfony service in order to not initialize Twig Environment every time.

Note that renderer in this case won't have any of Symfony's Twig Extensions, you'll have to add them manually.

If possible, try to avoid this, and put templates into `app/Resources/views` or `src/AppBundle/Resources/views` directories.

Comment: Why do you need to declare `$twig`?

Comment: @A.L Because `twig` you would get from the container does not work with arbitrary paths. Symfony does not pass `\Twig_Loader_String()` to it, so it would expect a template to be in specific locations.

Comment: I suggest you to add this comment to your question, using `\Twig_Environment(...` is not a common way.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a path like that :

```
return $this->render('Bundle:Something:file.html.twig', array(
    'varToSend' => $queryResult
));
```

And put your file in this folder :

```
src/Bundle/Resources/views/Something/file.html.twig
```